# Combine multiple csv files column wise with the header as file name

Tags: python, csv

I couldn't find the exact code on the platform which is why posting it for suggestions.

I have multiple CSV files (about 100) with the same data formats and header names.

```
 ,Mean,SD
1,96.432,13.899
2,96.432,13.899
3,96.432,13.899
4,96.432,13.899
5,96.432,13.899
```

I want to append all files column-wise so that I have them in one file. Also, the header of each data should be the file name so that I can follow which data belongs to which file. For example, above mean, sd--> another row of the file name.

Please guide me, as I am new to Python.

Thank you and regards,
Khan.

Comment: can you provide an example of the expected output? (for example for 2 files, "file1.csv" and "file2.csv")

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I want the output as below.  BT -  N - 015  BT -  N - 013  BT -  N - 012
 ,Mean,SD   ,Mean,SD   ,Mean,SD
1,96.432,13.899  1,107.068,20.890  1,105.122,31.229
2,96.432,13.899  2,107.068,20.890  2,105.122,31.229
3,96.432,13.899  3,107.068,20.890  3,105.122,31.229
4,96.432,13.899  4,107.068,20.890  4,105.122,31.229
5,96.432,13.899  5,107.068,20.890  5,105.122,31.229
6,96.432,13.899  6,107.068,20.890  6,105.122,31.229
7,96.432,13.899  7,107.068,20.890  7,105.122,31.229
8,96.432,13.899  8,107.068,20.890  8,105.122,31.229 The first cell shows the file name

Comment: I'm afraid I can't understand your specs re the output file, could you please [edit] your question, possibly adding an example of the intended output?

Comment: @Khan please edit your question and provide the output as text

Comment: First csv ( BT -  N - 015) has data: 
 ,Mean,SD 
1,96.432,13.899 
2,96.432,13.899 
3,96.432,13.899 
4,96.432,13.899 
5,96.432,13.899 
6,96.432,13.899 
7,96.432,13.899 
8,96.432,13.899 
9,96.432,13.899 
10,96.432,13.899 
11,96.432,13.899 and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to read and concatenate the files, together with [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) and a dictionary comprehension:

```
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob('/tmp/*.csv') # change the location/pattern accordingly
# if you have a list of files, use: files=['file1.csv', 'file2.csv'...]

df = pd.concat({fname.rsplit('/')[-1]: pd.read_csv(fname, index_col=0)
                for fname in files}, axis=1)
```

output:

```
>>> print(df)
  file1.csv         file2.csv        
       Mean      SD      Mean      SD
                                     
1    96.432  13.899    96.432  13.899
2    96.432  13.899    96.432  13.899
3    96.432  13.899    96.432  13.899
4    96.432  13.899    96.432  13.899
5    96.432  13.899    96.432  13.899
```

Saving to new file:

```
df.to_csv('concatenated_file.csv')
```

output:

```
,file1.csv,file1.csv,file2.csv,file2.csv
,Mean,SD,Mean,SD
 ,,,,
1,96.432,13.899,96.432,13.899
2,96.432,13.899,96.432,13.899
3,96.432,13.899,96.432,13.899
4,96.432,13.899,96.432,13.899
5,96.432,13.899,96.432,13.899
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am getting error 'ValueError: No objects to concatenate'

Comment: I guess you used `files = glob('/tmp/*.csv')` but you probably don't have the files in `/tmp`, change the code to use your folder

Comment: I have changed it to '/home/user/khan/Desktop/check/*.csv'

Comment: OK, and does it work as you expected? Note that if will read **all** the csv files in your `check` folder, and use the full name as header (I'll update the answer to keep only the file name)

Comment: No. It gives the error as I mentioned 'no objects to concatenate'. Thank you for changing the full name as the header but why it is giving me this error? Yes, I want to combine all csv files in the check folder.

Comment: what is the content of `files` after you run the `glob` command? If it is empty, then you did something wrong in the path, keep in mind that filename might be case sensitive on your system (likely)

Comment: Yes, you are right. The problem is with the path, which I couldn't understand. All csv files are in the check folder --> I am using this command --> files = glob('/home/user/khan/Desktop/check/*.csv') Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What does `ls /home/user/khan/Desktop/check/*.csv` give you in a terminal? Can you provide an example of a file name?

Comment: BT -  N - 015.csv , BT - A - 013.csv, BT - A - 014.csv and so on.... are file names. I checked the command which you mentioned, it is also giving error 'ls not defined'

Comment: What is your operating system? You ran the `ls` command in your OS shell, not python right?

Comment: Thank you. I tried and solved the issue using this command. path = r'C:\Users\khan\Desktop\check'

files = glob(path + "/*.csv") --> Now I have the solution but I can see header name as 'C:\Users\khan\Desktop\check\BT -  N - 015.csv', can I limit to just 'BT -  N - 015.csv' as header name?

Comment: OK, so you're using windows, looked like you were on unix given your previous path name (/home/user/...), then use `fname.rsplit(r'\')[-1]` in the code instead of `fname.rsplit('/')[-1]`

Comment: I used r'\' but it is giving error 'EOL while scanning string literal'

Comment: Sorry, try `fname.rsplit('\\')[-1]`

Answer (score 2):

The question was vague about formatting, so this may vary from the desired output.

```
filenames = [...]
dfs = []
for f in filenames:
    newdf = pd.read_csv(f)
    newdf.rename(columns={'Mean': 'Mean ' + f, 'SD': 'SD ' + f})
    dfs.append(newdf)
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: This won't perform a column-wise concatenation

Answer (score 0):

**you can use pandas to work with**

```
In [3]: import pandas  

                                                                                                                           

In [4]: import pandas as pd                                                                                                                           

In [13]: ls                                                                                                                                           
abc1.csv  abc.csv

In [14]: df = pd.read_csv('abc.csv')                                                                                                                  

In [15]: df1 = pd.read_csv('abc1.csv')                                                                                                                

In [16]: df                                                                                                                                           
Out[16]: 
        Mean      SD
0  1  96.432  13.899
1  2  96.432  13.899


In [16]: df                                                                                                                                           
Out[16]: 
        Mean      SD
0  1  96.432  13.899
1  2  96.432  13.899

In [17]: df1                                                                                                                                          
Out[17]: 
        Mean      SD
0  3  96.432  13.899
1  4  96.432  13.899
2  5  96.432  13.899

In [18]: df.append(df1)                                                                                                                               
Out[18]: 
        Mean      SD
0  1  96.432  13.899
1  2  96.432  13.899
0  3  96.432  13.899
1  4  96.432  13.899
2  5  96.432  13.899

In [19]: ds = df.append(df1)                                                                                                                          

In [20]: ds                                                                                                                                           
Out[20]: 
        Mean      SD
0  1  96.432  13.899
1  2  96.432  13.899
0  3  96.432  13.899
1  4  96.432  13.899
2  5  96.432  13.899



In [21]: ds.to_csv('file1.csv')  


In [23]: ls                                                                                                                                           
abc1.csv  abc.csv  file1.csv
```

**To deal with multiple files**

```
In [82]: import  pandas as pd                                                                                                                         

In [83]: import os, glob                                                                                                                              

In [84]: s = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'*.csv'))                                                                                             

In [85]: s                                                                                                                                            
Out[85]: 
['/home/thinkpad/Desktop/stackoverflow/abc1.csv',
 '/home/thinkpad/Desktop/stackoverflow/abc.csv']


In [90]: df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['in','Mean','SD']) 
    ...: for i in s: 
    ...:     df1 = pd.read_csv(i) 
    ...:     print(df1.head()) 
    ...:     df = df.append(df1) 

In [91]: df                                                                                                                                           
Out[91]: 
  in    Mean      SD
0  3  96.432  13.899
1  4  96.432  13.899
2  5  96.432  13.899
0  1  96.432  13.899
1  2  96.432  13.899
```

Comment: There are 100 files ;)

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I have multiple files, 100 or so; how can I rename them as different data frames. Can I use this code for self naming as data frame?

Comment: dear sir, I have resolved your problem now you can have look, Now your folder can have 100's or 1000's It will work very smoothly.
Thankyou